# SOQL Use LIKE with EXPLICIT Collections

Tags: apex, soql

This syntax works ok for using like with collection :

```
Set<String> setAccNames = new Set<String>();
setAccNames.add('ABC');
setAccNames.add('XYZ');
setAccNames.add('RST');
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN :setAccNames];
```

Also this syntax works with the IN operator :

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Email IN ('ab.com', 'mo5stjessica@gmail.com' );
```

But unfortunately this is not working :

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Email **LIKE** ('ab.com', 'mo5stjessica@gmail.com' );
```

I got Error : 'Unknown error parsing query'

Any idea ?
I must do the query like that because it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon(;) from the end of the query.
Run the below query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Email IN ('ab.com', 'mo5stjessica@gmail.com')
```

Comment: @hcohen It' working fine at my developer console. Just try it and if it really helps you, please accept the answer and upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my question update i had mistake